# Imgur upload box is not keyboard-friendly

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, images, editor, imgur

We have lots of [wonderful keyboard shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6402/what-are-the-most-useful-hotkeys-tips-in-the-wmd-editor/96590#96590) with which to compose an answer.  One of these is  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>, which brings up the image uploader.

Unfortunately, the resulting box requires me to remove my hands from the keyboard and click "Browse" before I get back to a browser file select tool which is keyboard friendly.
Attempting to tab to the "Browse" button moves the focus around in the greyed-out background, and you cannot type in the file input box.  Even if you could, it points to `C:\fakepath\` (due to [this deferred bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68471/the-image-uploader-shows-fakepath-as-path-when-using-chrome)), so typing the path there wouldn't work.

Please don't make me reach for my mouse.

Comment: a-frickin'-men!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per Jeff:

> I don't care about the styling. Go with the browser default. Make it so!
>   <sub>`<snip type="26 relevant YouTube videos"></snip>`</sub>

So after the next build, you'll see the standard browser file chooser element, and the initial keyboard focus is on it.

Regarding "typing in the file input box" – with the old way, that certainly wouldn't have been possible (it would be a huge security hole in the browser); but I don't know of any browser that allows you to directly type in the *real* input box either. If you have a browser that allows that, you can obviously use this now.

Answer (score 11):

Per balpha:

> Not going to work -- the "browse" button and filename box aren't real, they just make you *think* you're clicking them. In reality, you're clicking the hidden file input.
>
> http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html
>
> well, unless you want to drop the custom styling...
>
> I can play around with it, but if you really want to make it feel like those are *real* controls and not just BSing the user, that's going to be complicated, if possible at all.

Comment: Ah, so that's what's going on.  I'll wait for @balpha to 'play around with it' before accepting an answer.