# "Upload Image" dialog should focus "Upload" button after an image is selected

Tags: feature-request, images, uploader

When this dialogue comes up, *after the user is done selecting an image*, is it possible to have the "Upload" button in focus? For those of us who close the preceding OS file selection dialog by hitting Enter, and are then forced to switch to the mouse to click Upload on this one (tabbing just goes through a hundred other places first, on the background page).

[image: the upload dialog, Upload button noticeably unfocused]

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96660/imgur-upload-box-is-not-keyboard-friendly, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119269/image-upload-improvement-request-reduce-clicks-required-to-link-images, and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96915/marvelous-new-keyboard-friendly-image-uploader-has-some-issues.