# When trying to upload an image from web in chat, autofocus on the text field

Tags: feature-request, chat, images

Tiny little feature request/bug I've noticed and drives me crazy like a thorn in my neck.

When I open the upload dialog and choose "from web", the logical action for me would be to use the input box to paste a link. So please autofocus on that field when I chose the "from web" tab.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122732/upload-image-dialog-should-focus-upload-button-after-an-image-is-selected