# Focus on the 'Confirm' button after pasting into the picture pop-up

Tags: feature-request, bug, uploader, keyboard-shortcuts, focus

I often find my self wanting to copy an image (not the url, but the image) and 'paste' it into an answer.

Here's what I mean by copy:

[image: "copy image" highlighted in right-click menu]

To do this I love to use the Stack Exchange keyboard shortcuts.

1. <kbd>ctrl+g</kbd> to open 'Graphics' pop up
2. <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd> to paste from clipboard
3. <kbd>enter</kbd> to [image: Confirm!]....wait no. Where's the focus?

Here's what Step 3 looks like:

[image: Step three]

Go try it, it's not as smooth as it could be. I've got to *touch my mouse*!

Could we put the focus on the 'confirm' button, after pasting a raw image?

Not sure if Bug or Feature so tagging as both.

Related: [Imgur upload box is not keyboard-friendly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96660/imgur-upload-box-is-not-keyboard-friendly?rq=1) and [Image uploader is not usable with the keyboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269729/image-uploader-is-not-usable-with-the-keyboard)

Comment: I'm on mobile, so can't check, but would a "Tab" work? Or is there _no_ focus?

Comment: @colejohnson there's no focus at all

Comment: @ColeJohnson I've [hopefully] clarified the question now.

Comment: Focus is not required actually, client side code can easily detect ENTER key press and act accordingly. :)

Comment: This has since been fixed, I'm just looking to see if there was a good dupe target?

Comment: There's [this old one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122732/1017231) (also lacking any sort of response)