# Image uploader is not usable with the keyboard

Tags: feature-request, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, uploader

How can I upload an image with the keyboard?

There's a keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, but it brings up a pop-up that's decidedly keyboard-hostile. Most key presses keep being sent to the editor widget:

- Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> the right number of times eventually highlights “link from the web”, and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> lets me type a link. That's doable, but that *right number of times* bit is annoyingly large.
  (By the way, why isn't the text box to type/paste a link shown as soon as the popup appears?)
- I haven't found a way to activate the button to enter a file name.

Please make the image uploader usable with the keyboard.

Comment: This should be as simple as re-setting the focus when the popup loads. Can't say for certain, of course, but this certainly sounds like it could be done fairly easily, and would save a lot of hassle.